# displaying fahrenheit temperature formatting in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a temperature value that I need to show to the user in iOS, how can I have that special character show up for fehrenhiet ie :    37°F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and past it into the code.

```
double temperature = 37.2f;
NSString *temperatureString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f°F", temperature];
NSLog(@"%@", temperatureString);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not accepting earlier but I just realised that I have to do that.

Comment: Instead of using two separate characters (the degree symbol and the letter F), just use the Unicode character U+2109 (`℉`).